Why does Fetch Promise deliver?
I'm using strapi in my project, but when I fetch, it gives me promise instead of json
my code :
const [products, setproducts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            try {
                let res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/categories");
                let data = res.json()
                setproducts(data);
                console.log(data)
            }
            catch (err) { alert(err) }
        })();
    }, []);  

The response the Postman gave me has JSON

await res.json()?

fetch json() is aslo async

This could be something to do with your API application. Considering you're sending a request to localhost 1337, I'd suggest you've forgotten an async/await statement in your server-side application. Please provide said server application's source code.

@NikkieDev If that were the case, we wouldn't see a promise here, because it couldn't be serialized and sent over the network.

but it interesting that in whole fetch spec there is nothing about which methods are promise and which are sync executed, very strange.  @AmirHosein - general suggestion - if you see a promise, then  "await" it if you in async routine or , promise.them() if "sync"

I against to close, because there is documentation flaw, better to find a way to escalate to w3c , officially await (await fetch(url)).json()) only in mdn examples :(
on spec it is https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-json and they all not mention that there is Promise returned,

@zb' It's there in the spec via the Response includes Body; (not to confuse it with the static member that's also there). This means that Response has all the members of Body, which has the .json() method

Because the .json() method returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the response body text as JSON.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#instance_methods
That means you have to await response.json() as well.

in this link is nothing about promise in json() method :)

@zb' Yes there is. It literally says there that the json method returns a promise and how it resolves. Please don't downvote because you were too hasty to actually read it.

ok, strange, but it still not spec, ah I understand, they  have instance and static methods sections, this is why I not  see correct place'

@zb' It is indeed the spec. Fetch returns a promise that resolves into a Response. This spec is of that very Response.

Yes see now, just because static in front :(

@zb' I think you might be confused because you click on .json method. But you have to read the line below it, not click on it. I'm almost literally quoting it in my answer.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

you can use  to await the json() method on the res object returned by fetch.  json() method returns a promise as well, so you need to await it to get the data from res object


const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            let res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/categories");
            let data = await res.json(); // Await the json() method
            setProducts(data);
            console.log(data);
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    })();
}, []);




Lol, I forgot that .json() is a promise. This should solve it @AmirHosein
